# Dynamically loading external script doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm building a one-page website. Attached an external html into another html. CSS an HTML loads but the script of the external doesn't?

```
<button>
    <a class="cd-btn-services" href="technical-services.html" id="mylink" data-type="page-transition">click me</a>
</button>


var myLink = document.getElementById('mylink');

myLink.onclick = function(){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "Public/Scripts/filename.js."; 
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your src:

```
script.src = "Public/Scripts/filename.js";
```

not

```
script.src = "Public/Scripts/filename.js.";
```

your code worked for me

Comment: when the button is clicked, it loads the external file which is an accordion. Problem is, the script on the external html for the accordion doesnt seem to load also to allow it to expand.

Comment: In addition, you can remove the ` script.type = "text/javascript";` line completely as HTML5 script elements are defaulted to 'text/javascript' by default. You may also want to lose the 'return false' as it doesn't look like you are using a return value in the code.